# Protecting a Codeigniter File Upload controller

Tags: security, codeigniter, authentication, upload, token

I have a controller called "File_upload" which is called via ajax from a File Uploader form. As part of security hardening I want to make sure that the File_upload controller cannot be called via the browser or by any other "hack", and that it can only be called via the form.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this > would it be done via some kind of token? I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas, or code snippets that might set me off in the right direction.

I am assuming that the File Upload form would have to pass some kind of information to the controller, and the controller would check for its presence before proceeding. The application is undergoing some stringent security testing next week on the File Uploader so I would like to get a head start in making sure that the uploader cannot be overridden by a malicious hacker.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

"cannot be called via the browser or by any other "hack", and that it can only be called via the form. "

This doesn't actually make a lot of sense - you can't control where it is called from, only what information is passed to your server's function.

You CAN control a few things, such as whether or not it is an ajax request:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html
$this->input->is_ajax_request()

So yes, you could set up some sort of token system to check that the request has the required info. Normally, just checking that the user making the request is logged in should be enough; let your login authentication system handle security

If you aren't clear what I meant in my first line about not controlling where it is called from, give this a read:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/12/web-form-security-avoiding-common-mistakes